# ReduceByKeyAndWindow does repartitioning twice on recovering from checkpoint

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using spark streaming check-pointing mechanism and reading the data from Kafka. The window duration for my application is 2 hrs with a sliding interval of 15 minutes.

So, my batches run at following intervals...

- 09:45
- 10:00
- 10:15
- 10:30
- and so on

When my job is restarted, and recovers from the checkpoint it does the re-partitioning step twice for each 15 minute job until the window of 2 hours is complete. Then the re-partitioning  takes place only once.

For example - when the job recovers at 16:15 it does re-partitioning for the 16:15 Kafka stream and the 14:15 Kafka stream as well. Also, all the other intermediate stages are computed for 16:15 batch. I am using `reduceByKeyAndWindow` with inverse function. Now once the 2 hrs window is complete 18:15 onward re-partitioning takes place only once. Seems like the checkpoint does not have `RDD` stored for beyond 2 hrs which is my window duration.  Because of this my job takes more time than usual.

Is there a way or some configuration parameter which would help avoid repartitioning twice ?

[image: Attached the DAG Visualisation showing 2 repartitions]

Thanks !
Kundan

Comment: Do you mind posting your code showing how you checkpoint and restart your process?

Comment: @RohanAletty...I am just specifying the checkpointing directory and using reduceByKeyAndWindow with the inverse inside the aggregations that I am doing.